# C# object unique

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, object, uniqueidentifier

In my asp.net web applicaiton I am using objects to add infomation to database something like this

```
Employee emp1 = new Employee()
emp1.name = "something"
emp1.age = some age
InsertEmployee(emp)
```

This code works fine. But however if multiple users are trying to insert the employee data then  data gets mixed up.

User then calls up and says , "The age I entered is different from what it is showing for employee XXX.

How to fix this ? Whats the good method to make the object unique ?.

Thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the object Unique by using Guid type. emp1.Guid = Guid.NewGuid();

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different ideas here:

1. [Primary key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189039.aspx) in the database.  In this case, you could use an integer value for the ID and this is a way to keep all the employees sorted in a relatively clean manner using some of SQL Server's built-in functionality.
2. [GUIDs.](http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/generate_new_guid_uniqueidentifier_in_sql_server.aspx)  In this case, you'd assign a new GUID to each employee and have this be a unique value for each employee.  This can be done in the DB though you could also do it in the C# code if you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

```
User then calls up and says , "The age I entered is different from what it is showing for employee XXX.
```

How are you updating the user results?

```
 How to fix this ? Whats the good method to make the object unique ?.
```

You need to add primary key in your database. And do all your database operations against that primary key. You can read about SQL Keys [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/08/sql-server-%E2%80%93-2008-creating-primary-key-foreign-key-and-default-constraint/) .Example

```
update yourTable
SET
  YourColumnName = YourValue
Where
  tableId = Idofthisemployee
```